# cout (<<) overloaded operator not printing subtracted matrices

Tags: c++, matrix

I am trying to subtract two matrices and print them in this format cout << (mat1 - mat2 ) << endl ; but the cout is not working, it works when i print one matrix

here is the code

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <iomanip>
   using namespace std;

     struct matrix {
        int** data;
         int row, col;
      };

  void createMatrix (int row, int col, int num[], matrix& mat) {
       mat.row = row;
       mat.col = col;
       mat.data = new int* [row];

      for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
           mat.data[i] = new int [col];

      for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
          for (int j = 0; j < col; j++){
              mat.data[i][j] = num[i * col + j];
      }}} ;
```

here is the function someone told me to use " const" i did but it still not working

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out  ,const matrix&  mat ) {

    for (int i =0 ; i< mat.row ; i++) {
         for (int j =0 ; j < mat.col ; j++) {
             out << mat.data [i] [j] << " " ;
    }
    cout << endl ;
   }
  return out ;
 };
```

when I print it in this function it works well but does not work in the main

```
    matrix operator-  (matrix mat1, matrix mat2) {
         matrix  matt  ;
         if ((mat1.row == mat2.row) && (mat1.col == mat2.col)) {;
              for (int i =0 ; i< mat1.row ; i++) {
                    for (int j =0 ; j < mat1.col ; j++) {
                        matt.data[i][j] = ((mat1.data [i][j]) - (mat2.data [i][j]))  ;
                        }
                        }}

       else {
         cout  << " the matrixs dont have the same dimensions " << endl ;
         }
return matt ;
 };




   int main()  {
  int data1 [] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
  int data2 [] = {13,233,3,4,5,6};
  int data3 [] = {10,100,10,100,10,100,10,100};

matrix mat1, mat2, mat3;
createMatrix (4, 2, data1, mat1);
createMatrix (2, 3, data2, mat2);
createMatrix (4, 2, data3, mat3);

 cout << mat1 << endl;
 cout << mat2 << endl;
 cout << mat3 << endl;

 cout << ( mat3 - mat1 ) << endl ;
```

};

Comment: You forgot to initialize your returned `matt` object with data storage and sizes. But the side effect would be that you return temporary matrix, which leaks out allocated memory, since you never deleted it

Comment: Thats why we use constructors in C++. No chance of forgetting to call.

Comment: "`struct matrix { int** data; int row, col; };`" Don't! Jut don't! Encapsulate a `std::vector<int>` and provide a member function to access it with pseudo 2d indexes like `index = row * num_cols + col`.

Comment: @Swordfish   I didn't like that either but that's the way my doctor wants it soo....

Comment: @nadia Get a new one. Yours is broken.

Answer (score 0):

don't send the matrix by reference send it by value like that and you don't need to pass it as constant

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out  ,matrix  mat ) {

for (int i =0 ; i< mat.row ; i++) {
     for (int j =0 ; j < mat.col ; j++) {
         out << mat.data [i] [j] << " " ;
}
cout << endl ;
}
return out;
};
```